# Why was \b introduced while \s match string borders in regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I see that there is the `\b` which I have never used and I was wondering if someone can give me use cases when it is not possible to do without `\b`.

Comment: Read this description: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html it helped me a lot.

Comment: \s does *not* match "string borders". It matches whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They match on different things - `\s` matches on whitespace, `\b` on word boundaries.

One good example is the character `.`.

In the string `hello.hi`:

`\s` will not match `.`, but `\b` will match before and after it.

Comment: `\b` doesn't match characters, it matches word boundaries.

Answer (score 6):

> I was wondering if someone can give me use cases when it is not possible to do without \b.

The expression `\b` is just a convenient shorthand for what you can already do with other constructs.

For example, if your regular expression engine has lookarounds then `\b` is equivalent to the following longer expression:

```
(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(?=\w)
```

Similarly `\w`, `\d`, etc. are just shorthand for what already can be done using character classes, for example `[A-Za-z0-9_]` or `[0-9]`. You typically want to use the short version because writing out the full definition each time is cumbersome, harder to read and increases the risk of making an error.

Answer (score 2):

They are completely different things.

`\s` is a "**whitespace character**". That means it is a shortcut to a predefined character class that contains whitespace characters like `\t, \r, \n` or a space. `\s` matches one out of those characters.

`\b` is a "**word boundary**". It is a zero width assertion and is related to the predefined character class `\w`. Zero width assertion means, it has a width of 0, i.e. it does not match a character. It does match a position that fulfills an assertion. The assertion here would be a word character on one side and a non-word character on the other side. [Mark provided already the long version of `\b`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379440/626273) and [Oded an example where `\b` would match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379388/626273).

`\w` is a "**word character**", means it contains something like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. In some languages it is based on Unicode and contains all letters.